# Add custom button in buttons-collection

Tags: javascript, datatables

I want to add custom button under **.buttons-collection**. See the snapshot and example below.

```
buttons: [{extend : 'collection',
                         text : '<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>',
                         buttons : [ 'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print']}]
```

[image]

Button should be named as 'Report Issue'. By clicking on the button it should run the JS below (with table name). This code sends out email with the description of issue (issue related to the table) -

```
   onclick=JS("function() {
$(location).attr('href', 'mailto:xxx.com?subject='
              + encodeURIComponent('Issue on Table' + this.table.name)
              + '&body=' 
              + encodeURIComponent('Please check issue on table ' + '\"' + this.table.name + '\"'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a `<table>` with an ID of `myTable` and a name of `Your Name Here` (just as a placeholder), you can use the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#myTable').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      { extend : 'collection',
        text : '<i class="fa fa-bars">buttons</i>',
        buttons: [
          'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print',
          {
            text: 'Report Issue',
            action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
              reportIssue(e, dt, node, config);
            }
          }
        ]
      }]
  } );

  // e - the button click event
  // dt - the datatable object
  // node - button node
  // config - the button's config (e.g. 'text')
  function reportIssue(e, dt, node, config) {    
    var tableName = $('#myTable').attr('name');
    alert( 'The "' + config.text + '" button was clicked\n' 
        + 'for the "' + tableName + '" table.' );
  }

});
```

The heart of the solution is this part, where the custom button is declared:

```
{
  text: 'Report Issue',
  action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
    reportIssue(e, dt, node, config);
  }
}
```

Points to note:

I added the word "buttons" to the main button, just so it was not empty:

[image]

When you click on that, you see the following button set:

[image]

After that, it's up to you what you add to the `reportIssue()` function. You may not need any of the variables passed to it. Probably not, based on the sample JS in the question (I used an alert, just for testing).

Comment: Thank you. The button collection is nice - I had not seen that before.

Comment: Great. .attr('id') works. Not sure why .attr('name') is not working?

Comment: Last question - Is there any way it takes automatically from table (instead of specifying explicity #myTable here -   var tableName = $('#myTable').attr('name');

Comment: Does your table have a name attribute? `<table id="myTable" name="Your Name Here" ...>`

Comment: I would just add it to the function call in the table's configuration: `reportIssue(e, dt, node, config, 'myTable');` That way, you can re-use the function across tables. But you have to hard-code within each table config. There may be a fancier way to get the table name from the DataTaables object. I don't know it. That could be a new question.